# Find the equation ( hard one for me )

Tags: sequences-and-series

1+3+9+27+...+x=121 ?

Hello,

My friend who is good at math sent this to me
he told me to find the answer but im not sure
how to start it...

Can anyone give me any hints ?

Comment: $3^{0}+3^{1}+3^{2}+3^{3}+3^{4}=1+3+9+27+81=121?$

Comment: ignore the ...s

Comment: [Geomteric series](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Geometric_series)

Answer (score 2):

$$a+ar+ar^2+\cdots+ar^{n-1}=\frac{a(r^n-1)}{r-1}$$
This is a well-known formula for finite [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).
Thus
$$\begin{align}1+3+3^2+\cdots+3^{n-1}=\frac{3^n-1}{3-1}&=0.5\cdot 3^n-0.5=121\\\iff 3^n=\frac{121.5}{0.5}=243&=3^5\iff n=5,\end{align}$$
since $f(x)=3^x, x\in\mathbb R$ is strictly increasing (and thus injective).

Comment: Thank you User314, this is the answer that i wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to convert $121$ from base $10$ to base $3$. It can be easily seen that $$121=(11111)_{3}$$
i.e., $$121=1\times 3^4+1\times 3^3+1\times 3^2+1\times 3^1+1\times 3^0$$
  Now, what is the value of x?

Comment: Nice answer, but easy? How about use pre-algebra to figure out what number is in the blank space... :-)

Comment: You are right. But even if we are allowed to use a calculator, we  need to add numbers from 1 to an unknown number until we reach 121... But not for this case.(121 in the base 3 reveals x fast)

Comment: Absolutely, yours is the more general and more interesting answer. :-) But, I'm waiting for someone to come along and claim that it is easily solved by considering functors and morphisms in category theory. Even more general and more interesting... All to solve a primary school subtraction problem. Then someone else could come along and show that an infinite number of functions could model 1,3,9,27... and add to 127, so the numbers in the blank is impossible to determine.